# Installing FlickrFaves on a opensuse - Linux box with YAST

Tags: linux, opensuse-12.2

I want to install FlickrFaves on a OpenSuse machine.
I have running opensuse version 12.2.

Well, FlickrFaves comes in the current version: 2.0.4 with some special JAR-File, But my local linux-geeks recomend me to install all the stuff I need with YAST.

What should I do now?

see the link to http://magnusvk.com/flickrfaves

Comment: Have you trided the e-mail link for Comments, questions and bugs? mailto:hello@magnusvk.com

Comment: good evening dear Carl. Well i will do so. thx for the advice